# Why is Scipy's cross correlation function giving incorrect results for audio signals

Tags: python, audio

I'm trying to calculate the location of a sound source using TDOA, by cross correlating audio recordings from different microphones and getting the time delay. I am fairly confident that the recording start times are synchronized to 0.01ms or less. The microphones are all plugged into a RaspberryPi.

However, when testing in a room with the microphones set up about 15 meters apart, the cross correlation is giving very incorrect and unreasonable results. I divide the lag in array distance (which are audio data recorded at a specific sample rate) by the sample rate, which should give the delay in seconds right? But the code would say that the delay is 1-2 second or more, when the entire recording is only 3 seconds. The recorded sound is otherwise crystal clear, with almost zero background noise, and several loud, prominent claps.

Here's the code I used:

```py
from scipy import signal
from scipy.io import wavfile

r1,s1 = wavfile.read('near output.wav'). #r1 is sample rate, s1 is data
r2,s2 = wavfile.read('far output.wav')
correlation = signal.correlate(s1, s2, mode="full")
lags = signal.correlation_lags(s1.size, s2.size, mode="full")
lag = lags[np.argmax(correlation)]
print(f"Delay: {lag / r1}")
```